# Как изменить кодировку neovim?

Tags: vim

Есть программа на C++, есть вывод:
В Codeblocks(IDE): `cout <<"привет русские буквы";`

В Neovim это превращается в `cout <<"їїїїїї їїїїїїї їїїїї";`

Если написать этот же текст на русском в Neovim, и открыть c Codeblocks, в Codeblocks тоже будут рандомные символы. Я так понял, редакторы кода используют разные кодировки для русского языка (с латиницей все в порядке). Как можно поменять кодировку Neovim, или что делать, если дело не в кодировке? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Reloading_a_file_using_a_different_encoding

Comment: Везде используйте UTF-8

Comment: Спасибо огромное, помогло!